# TimeTrigger (C# UWP) срабатывает не вовремя

Tags: c#, uwp, windows-10

Задача следующая: запускать фоновую задачу в определённое время ежедневно (время настраивается пользователем). Решаю так: при изменении времени (или первичном запуске приложения) определяю время до запуска, если оно меньше 15 минут, то прибавляю сутки, если больше или равно, то устанавливаю в это время. Это задача одноразовая.
При её завершении (событие `OnCompleted`) снимаю эту задачу (можно и не снимать, т.к. она и так однократная), и регистрирую периодическую на сутки.
Но для отладки использую короткие интервалы: для первого запуска 15 мин, для периодического 20. Но триггер срабатывает как-то по-своему. Вот примерный график срабатывания:

```
14:52 - запуск приложения
14:53 - 1 мин - первое срабатывание
15:08 - 15 мин - первое периодическое
15:24 - 16 мин - второе периодическое
15:54 - 20 мин - третье периодическое
16:10 - 16 мин - 4е периодическое
16:25 - 15 мин - 5е периодическое
```

и т.п.
Судя по отладчику, всё работает верно, задачи регистрируются именно те, которые нужны.
Сталкивался ли кто-нибудь с подобной проблемой? Или это нормальное поведение в интервалах, близких к 15 минутам?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Срабатывание в точное время не гарантируется, поэтому самое оптимальное запускать задачу за 10 минут, до времени, которое задал пользователь, а вот само действие (уведомление или плитка) планировать на нужное время. Благо и плитки и уведомления позволяют задать запланированное время срабатывания.

Answer (score 2):

С UWP я плотно не знаком, но насколько помню модель background task'ов из старого Windows Phone, в ней точное срабатывание по таймеру не гарантируется. Все зависит от состояния устройства: загрузка процессора, памяти, состояние аккумулятора. Возможно в Windows 10 аналогичная модель. Почитайте внимательно [раздел документации по таскам в Windows 10](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh977046.aspx), может быть там упоминается об этом.

Чтобы проверить это предположение, можно отключить все приложения, которые могут потреблять много процессора/памяти и/или запускаться периодически в фоне, и запустить ваше приложение еще раз.

Comment: Тестирую на настольном компьютере, и проца и памяти с избытком. Документацию, конечно, прочитал, ничего подобного не нашёл.